# How to delete selected Item from a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have created a DeleteSlectedItemListBox Method below which has a code that deleted a selected item in the list-box when delete button has been clicked. However it does not seem like its working.

The code has to delete whats on the list-box as well in the text-file.
How do I do that ?

```
 private void DeleteSelectedItemListBox()
 {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string FileName = (@"C: \Users\StanleyM\Desktop\PhoneBook\PhoneBook\bin\Debug\Personal.text");
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(FileName);
    string line = "";
    int Counter = -1;

    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in line)
        {
            if (item.ToString() == SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                Counter--;
                dt.Clear();
                ListBox.Remove(line);
            }           
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVVM pattern you can bind in `XAML` selected item and your list like `ObservableCollention`. `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}" SelectedItems="{Binding YourSelectedItem}"></ListBox>`
Then in your deleting method you can try:

```
private void DeleteSelectedItemListBox()
{    
    var deletingNumber = YourList.IndexOf(YourSelectedItem);
    var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
    allLines.RemoveAt(deletingNumber);
    File.WriteAllLines(path,allLines.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I click the deleted button System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\StanleyM\Desktop\PhoneBook\PhoneBook\bin\Debug\Personal.text' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: It might works. Maybe your file is opened from other place and not closed, or you opened it with other program

Comment: Do you now how can I do live update in my ListBox for adding and deleting because most of the time when I add something on my Listbox I have to go out the app and start the app in order to see what I have added is there and what I have deleted is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
  {
    var index = listBox1.Items.IndexOf(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    RemoveTextLine(index);
  }

private void RemoveTextLine(int index){

  using(var sr = new StreamReader("C:\Users\StanleyM\Desktop\PhoneBook\PhoneBook\bin\Debug\Personal.text"))
  using(var sw = new StreamWriter("C:\Users\StanleyM\Desktop\PhoneBook\PhoneBook\bin\Debug\temp.text"))
  {
   int line=0;
   while((sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      if(line != index)
      sw.WriteLine(line);
      line ++;
   }
 }

  File.Delete("Personal.txt");
  File.Move(tempFile, "Personal.txt");
}
```

Try This

Comment: Thanks Shiwanka, The first While that is not in the method is it suppose to be in a different method? as well where does the tempFile come from as I getting error for that as well the index in my ViewModel?

Comment: declare some temp file pah and replace with that, i have done it already in the code.